# C++ - Why does int overflow still happen after modding 1'000'000'007?

Tags: c++, integer, overflow

Recently I am working on leetcode，here is one of question：
[enter link description here](https://leetcode-cn.com/problems/student-attendance-record-ii/submissions/)

And I worte code below：

```
class Solution {
public:
static constexpr int MOD = 1'000'000'007;
    int checkRecord(int n) {
        int dp[2][3];
        int dp2[2][3];
        memset(dp, 0, sizeof(dp));
        memset(dp2,0,sizeof(dp2));
        for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= 2; k++) {
                cout<<dp2[j][k]<<endl;
            }
        }
        dp[0][0] = 1;
        for(int i=1;i<n+1;i++){
            dp2[0][1] = dp[0][0]%MOD;
            dp2[1][1] = dp[1][0]%MOD;
            dp2[0][2] = dp[0][1]%MOD;
            dp2[1][2] = dp[1][1]%MOD;
            dp2[1][0] = (dp[0][0]+dp[0][1]+dp[0][2])%MOD;
            dp2[1][0] = (dp2[1][0]+dp[1][0]+dp[1][1]+dp[1][2])%MOD;
            dp2[0][0] = (dp[0][0]+dp[0][1]+dp[0][2])%MOD;            
            memcpy(dp, dp2, sizeof(dp));
        }
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= 2; k++) {
                sum = (sum + dp[j][k]) % MOD;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
};
```

One of case is "n = 10101".As far as I concened,after modding 1'000'000'007,one interger can not get integer overflow.But still overflow happens,here is the error.

```
Line 16: Char 51: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 1543295930 + 918080153 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:25:51
```

This happens in:

```
 dp2[1][0] = (dp2[1][0]+dp[1][0]+dp[1][1]+dp[1][2])%MOD;
```

So shouldn't equal happens after mod?Why does int overflow happens?

Thanks for reading,I know my English sucks.I would appriciate if there is any answer.

Comment: The problem is the summation, not the assignment. The summation comes first, and overflows. You need to do one addition at a time.

Comment: Seeing this code I am once more convinced that leetcode is a good place to learn problem solving skills but horrible for learning to be a good software engineer. Try to make datastructures that represent what you mean, don't put everything in meaningless arrays with memcpy's but use abstractions, and give variables meaningful names too

Answer (score 0):

In C++, `int` range from `-2147483648` to `2147483647` (`-2^31` -> `2^31 - 1`).
In your line of code:

```
dp2[1][0] = (dp2[1][0]+dp[1][0]+dp[1][1]+dp[1][2])%MOD;
```

The `dp2[1][0]+dp[1][0]+dp[1][1]+dp[1][2]` part is evaluated first, and since the `MOD` is `1e9+7`, it can sum up to `~3e9` in the worst case and overflowing. To fix it, just do it one at a time:

```
dp2[1][0] = (((dp2[1][0]+dp[1][0]+dp[1][1])%MOD)+dp[1][2])%MOD;
```

More reading : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm

Comment: `int` is popularly 32-bit, but it could be other sizes.  Depends on the platform and what the platform+compiler considers the *natural word size*.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.I try your way before I ask this question,it doesn't work still.But I try it with my computer and don't have any problem,So I think this error happens might because of compiler.

Comment: @周宁音 As a last resort, you can maybe try to switch all `int` for `long long`.

Answer (score 0):

Int is a 32-bit variable type so can take integers between approximately -2^32 and 2^32 which is arround 2,000,000,000.

`dp2[1][0] = (dp2[1][0]+dp[1][0]+dp[1][1]+dp[1][2])%MOD;`

Here you add up three integers, each can be up to 1,000,000,006, and the do % on them. So you have an int with value about 3,000,000,000 which int can not handle.